# Transitioning a circle to show

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I am attempting to make the borders of a circle from two different points start at the x axis of the circle and then from 0%-100% keyframes join to connect.

I figured out how to create a circle as an outer div and I broke it up into different quadrants. 1, 2, 3 and 4. However, right now my borders for the quadrants are all displaying on one line rather than taking on the border of the circle.

How can I make the quadrants borders show in a circle.

I have created an illustration of what I am trying to do below, as well as shown what I have done so far.

[image]

```css
.outer {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  position: relative;
}

.quad1,
.quad2 {
  left: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #e0e0e0;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-animation: circle 4s 1 normal forwards;
  animation: circle 4s 1 normal forwards;
}

.quad3,
.quad4 {
  left: 0%;
  border: 5px solid #e0e0e0;
  transform-origin: right top;
    -webkit-animation: circle 4s 1 normal forwards;
  animation: circle 4s 1 normal forwards;
}

.quad1,
.quad4 {
  top: 0%;
  border: 5px solid #e0e0e0;
    -webkit-animation: circle 4s 1 normal forwards;
  animation: circle 4s 1 normal forwards;
}

.quad2,
.quad3 {
  top: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #e0e0e0;
    -webkit-animation: circle 4s 1 normal forwards;
  animation: circle 4s 1 normal forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes circle {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes circle {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="quad1"></div>
  <div class="quad2"></div>
  <div class="quad3"></div>
  <div class="quad4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bit tricky, but a fun problem.

There are 4 quarter-circles. Two of them rotate 90˚ and the other two rotate 180˚ in twice the time. There are also two masks that hide the quarter-circles in quadrants 2 and 4 until they have rotated 90˚, at which point the masks' z-indexes change to no longer hide the quarter-circles.

Check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3x2L47Lv/4/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="spinner top topright"></div>
    <div class="spinner top topleft"></div>
    <div class="spinner bottom bottomleft"></div>
    <div class="spinner bottom bottomright"></div>
    <div class="mask q2"></div>
    <div class="mask q4"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    background: inherit;
}

.spinner {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid black;
    z-index: 10;
}

.top {
    top: 130px;
    left: 130px;
    border-radius: 0 0 130px 0;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;
    transform-origin: top left;
}

.bottom {
    border-radius: 130px 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.topright, .bottomleft {
    animation: rotate90 2s linear forwards;
}

.topleft, .bottomright {
    animation: rotate180 4s linear forwards;
}

.mask {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: 15;
    animation: mask 4s linear forwards;
}


.q2 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.q4 {
    top: 130px;
    left: 130px;
}


@keyframes rotate90 {
    0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(-90deg); }
}

@keyframes rotate180 {
    0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(-180deg); }
}

@keyframes  mask {
    0%   {z-index: 15}
    100% {z-index: 4}
}
```

**UPDATED:**

If you want it to complete a circle, then reverse, what you can do is *make all animation times the same*, then change the `@keyframes` to the following:

```
@keyframes rotate90 {
    0%       { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    25%, 75% { transform: rotate(-90deg); }
    100%     { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes rotate180 {
    0%  { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    50% { transform: rotate(-180deg); }
   100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes  mask {
    0%  {z-index: 15}
    50% {z-index: 4}
   100% {z-index: 15}
}
```

Fiddle example with effect reversing: https://jsfiddle.net/3x2L47Lv/6/

Comment: Awesome! That is absolutely perfect. I appreciate your effort. I was getting no where with my attempts.Mine were this bad ... https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=F1C7rAvHOU

Comment: How did you get the lines to match up perfect? I tried to increase the size, but now it is misaligned? https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=F1C7rAvHOU

Comment: @Becky To scale it, make `.wrapper` whatever width/height you need. Then make `.spinner` width/height half of `.wrapper`. Choose whatever border size you need for spinner, then make width/height/border/top/bottom for `.top`, `.bottom`, `.mask`, and `.q4` the `.spinner` width/height PLUS the `.spinner` border size. Does that make sense?

Comment: Gotcha. Perfect sense. One last question, if you don't mind. I am trying to change the duration for this and every time I change `.topleft, .bottomright {` it gets stuck mid way.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thid `.topright, .bottomleft {` has to be half of all of the other durations.

Comment: @Becky Yes, exactly.

Comment: I hate to be a pain, but you know this better than anyone. I am trying to modify it, so that when the circle becomes full, that it shortly after goes away, the same way it came to be. Basically a reverse order. I tried to modify it like this: `@keyframes rotate90 {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  50% { transform: rotate(-90deg); }
  100%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes rotate180 {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  50% { transform: rotate(-180deg); }
  100%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes  mask {
  0%   {z-index: 15}
  50% {z-index: 4}
}`

Comment: @Becky Sorry that it's a bit difficult to modify for your needs, but I've updated my answer to include reversing the effect.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it would be a better idea to make this two separate transition keyframes? What I mean by that, is to do the initial key frame and then do some sort of jQuery delay for the reversing keyframes to start? OR am I able to time it within the keyframes in a more specific way?

Comment: @Becky I think you might be better off adjusting the current keyframes to get a delay. Here's another fiddle that shows how to get a 20% delay, for example. Maybe you can look at this to see how to get the exact delay that you need? https://jsfiddle.net/3x2L47Lv/8/

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I knew you could change the percentages, but I thought the time had to be written inside of the keyframes for some reason. That last fiddles help out a lot! I wish I could up vote you 10 times for this. You helped a bunch and I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: How did you calculate the 90% rotate and 180% time? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: This. I was trying to make the 90 10% and 90%, but I couldn't figure out the 180 to make it work. `@keyframes rotate90 {
  0%  { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  20%, 80% { transform: rotate(-90deg); } /*20% because it's in between 0% and 40% (from below), and  80% because it's in between 60% (from below) and 100%*/
  100%  { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  
}

@keyframes rotate180 {
  0%  { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  40%, 60% { transform: rotate(-180deg); } /*difference between these two is the % delay*/
  100%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}`

Comment: @Becky Use rotate180 to decide what % of the time you want to delay for. For example, `@keyframes rotate180 { 20%, 80% { transform: rotate(-180deg); } }` gives a 60% delay. Then on rotate90 you need 10% and 90% because 10% is half between 0%-20% and 90% is half between 80%-100%.